# Does rationalizing the denominator lead to more or less round-off error?

Tags: computational-mathematics, floating-point

I evaluated $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ in Matlab, and got a slight difference: $0.707106781186547$ and $0.707106781186548$, respectively. Which is more accurate, the one with the denominator rationalized, or the one without it rationalized?

Comment: [This](http://goo.gl/OU37b) is what Google has to say about that.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure (hence the post as a comment rather than an answer); but I believe that the second would be more accurate due to the representation of a floating point as: $$\text{significant digits}\times2^{\text{exponent}}$$ If we assume that $\sqrt{2}$ is computed to the same accuracy in both cases, division by two can be done more precisely as the exponent only needs to be reduced by one as to opposed to a more complex operation when taking the reciprocal. However, like I said, this is a guess.

Comment: @Shaktal That was my suspicion as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the value is $0.707106781186547524400844362104849039284835937688474036588339...$, so the second is (marginally) closer.  I wouldn't expect there to be a uniform rule on which is more accurate, depending on what expressions you are considering.  The point about division by $2$ being exact in computer math does not extend to $\frac 1{\sqrt 3}$ versus $\frac {\sqrt 3}3$, for example.

Answer (score 1):

With e.g. IEEE floating point numbers, computing the square root and computing the reciprocal are *two* steps that can introduce rounding error. Division by $2$, however is an exact operation. Therefore, the second can be expected to be slightly less accurate (though of course the errors might even partially  cancel) and computing $\sqrt{0.5}$ should produce exactly the same result with the same error as the second expression.

Comment: Surely the second should be slightly __more__ accurate because division by $2$ is an exact operation (reducing the exponent by $1$)?